# How to pass value from an input to next page's input?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

I have a page where you can put a URL in an input textbox, but I also want to have a "mini version" on homepage that explains how it works. What I am trying to do is:

1. Have an input box for URL address
2. Have a button that takes you to actual page
3. Have text inside input on homepage already fill the input textbox in the actual page

Comment: Have a look at session storage. With that you could get the value and store it in session storage, and then retrieve it on the next page and use JavaScript to dynamically set the value from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try local storage or session storage
Following statements shows localStorage

```
// Store your value from one page
localStorage.setItem("values", "input_text");

// Retrieve the value from another page
var value = localStorage.getItem("values");
```

Following statements shows session Storage

```
// Store your value from one page
sessionStorage.setItem("values", "input_text");

// Retrieve the value from another page
var value = sessionStorage.getItem("values");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your actual page action method should be like this

```
public ActionResult ActualPage(string inputText)
{
    ViewBag.InputText = inputText;
    return View();
}
```

And then in actual page view you can use the value of input text like this `@ViewBag.InputText`.

The name of input textbox in homepage and name of parameter in action method must be same to work.